# Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. error with dehydrated tool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am trying to update certs on my servers with [dehydrated](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated) and [dehydrated-route53-hook-script](https://github.com/whereisaaron/dehydrated-route53-hook-script).

Here is the complete command and error:

```
./xsys renewcerts
Running: cd certificates && ./dehydrated --cron
# INFO: Using main config file ..config/certificates/config
Processing mydomain.org with alternative names: dev-mydomain.org
 + Checking domain name(s) of existing cert... unchanged.
 + Checking expire date of existing cert...
 + Valid till Apr 21 11:47:17 2019 GMT (Less than 30 days). Renewing!
 + Signing domains...
 + Generating private key...
 + Generating signing request...
 + Requesting new certificate order from CA...
 + Received 2 authorizations URLs from the CA
 + Handling authorization for dev-mydomain.org
 + Handling authorization for mydomain.org
 + 2 pending challenge(s)
 + Deploying challenge tokens...
Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
Could not find zone for dev-mydomain.org
Running: cd certificates && ./dehydrated --cleanup
```

Looks like the aws credentials are failing, but from everything I can tell those are OK. I last ran this ~60 days ago and it ran fine then and (as far as I know) nothing has changed.

Any ideas on where to look for a fix is appreciated.

## Update

I found that this command is failing:

```
$cli53 list
Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
    For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

So the root issue seems to be cli53. I have credentials in  `~/.aws/credentials` per docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with cli53. I had a symlink as follows...

```
ls -la .aws/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 myuser  staff    96 Apr  5 15:33 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 143 myuser  staff  4576 Apr  8 12:30 ..
lrwxr-xr-x    1 myuser  staff    69 Apr  5 15:33 credentials -> /Users/myuser/ansible/myapp/_secrets/aws_credentials
```

...but I had recently changed this path to:

`/Users/myuser/apps/myapp/_secrets/aws_credentials` so it was simply a failure of cli53 being able to find the appropriate credentials.